# Binaries slam toolbox galactic

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know if there are binaries released for the galactic version of the slam-toolbox and if not when will be it released?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379547/binaries-slam-toolbox-galactic/) by [charlie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/64524/charlie92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://build.ros2.org/job/Gbin_uF64__slam_toolbox__ubuntu_focal_amd64__binary/

It will be available in the first Galactic sync

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1